# Do processors have actual circuitry to aid exception handling?

Tags: exception, cpu

My question here is pretty simple: I want to know if processors try to help exception handling somehow. Would it be possible to completely remove overhead from exception handling and throwing if enough effort is put in designing a processor "exception-ready"?

Because as far as I know, all exception handling is done via software, and that always adds some overhead. Am I wrong?

-- edit

So, thanks for all the answers below. I appreciate. You have answered my question.

But just to clarify why I asked this: generally, people don't go too deep into optimizing exceptions because they all think "exceptions are for exceptional circumstances", and therefore they are no bottleneck.

I don't think exceptions should only be thrown under dramatic circumstances. What I think is, basically, that an exception should be thrown anytime a function cannot comply to what it promised to do.

If I say:

```
doSomethingImportant();
```

And if for *whatever* reason "something important" can't be done, this should throw an exception.

Of course, doSomethingImportant() might not be able to comply because the system ran out of memory (a dramatic problem), but I think we should be able to model simpler "I can't do that now/this time, sorry" into our software, embedded into our designs. I'd like to say that I think exceptions can be exceptional, yes, but they *are to be expected* like normal software flow, not as a "fatal error" from which the system has to "recover", nomsain?

And while big applications backed by nice data centers will hardly ever bottleneck because of exception handling, please don't forget there's market for embedded devices where resources are counted, and exception handling *does* have an impact (which is what I'm aiming for).

I personally find exceptions quite expressive, and I'd like to use them in embedded devices with as much "overhead" as I would get by returning "-1" and checking that with an "if".

Comment: Exceptions will always be slow, because they're by definition *exceptional*, and the way to make things fast is to optimize for the common case, not the exceptional one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Instruction Set Architecture* documentations, *exceptions* are abnormal situations for processors (like zero-divide, illegal instructions, etc..). They are usually translated to *interrupts* (but most interrupts are *external* signals to the processor).

In *programming language* specifications, *exceptions* are non-local control flow constructs, usually involving some kind of call stack unwinding.

I believe that recent micro-architectures handle specially the *stack pointer* (for instance w.r.t. caching and instruction scheduling). They probably have some circuits dedicated to stack pointers changes required by programming language exceptions.

Some languages and implementations have better exception semantics and machinery than others. For example, Ocaml exception handling is faster than C++ one (at least with the GCC compiler).

Comment: Clear, concise, and unbiased like my original question. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

There are generally two types of exception handling:

1. The language exception. (the kind that you throw in C++/Java or any other language)
2. Hardware exceptions. (signals, seg-faults, misalignment, etc...)

I'm assuming you're talking about the first one. As of right now, no I don't think any processor has such support. Although I'm not a hardware designer, here are my arguments for why this is the case, as well as why exception handling may never be implemented in hardware.

1. Different languages have different exception handling protocols. C++ maybe different from Java, C#, etc... Stack unwinding and destructor calls will complicate this process.
2. **Is exception handling even a bottleneck?** The majority of the highly-optimized HPC performance-critical applications don't use exception handling anyway. Most of the OOP-oriented code that relies on exception handling is typically bottlenecked by other factors. (such as branching, cache, memory, etc...)

So adding hardware support for exception handling doesn't actually help the right user-base.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe they do, at least not currently. Exception handling isn't part of machine code, it's a feature of higher-level languages that can be implemented fairly easily through registers and call stacks, interrupts and... other things... and a compiler can choose to implement exception handling however it wants.

So yes, it always adds some overhead. However, I don't see much of a point in adding exception-handling to any CPU instruction sets just because. Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances; if they're causing performance problems from being thrown around too much, something's wrong in the code.